# Scala Option? Why does Some not inherit AnyVal and why is it not a value type?

Tags: scala

Why does Scala Some not inherit from AnyVal so that it uses the value type feature and save the boxing costs?

Something like:

```
sealed trait TestOption[+A] extends Any {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def get: A
}

final case class TestSome[+A](val x: A) extends AnyVal with TestOption[A] {
  def isEmpty = false
  def get = x
} 

case object TestNone extends TestOption[Nothing] {
  def isEmpty = true
  def get = throw new NoSuchElementException("None.get")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation for [Value Classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html):

> Summary of Limitations
>
> A value class
>
> - must have only a primary constructor with exactly one public, **val parameter whose type is not a value class**. (From Scala 2.11.0, the
>     parameter may be non-public.)
> - may not have specialized type parameters.
> - may not have nested or local classes, traits, or objects
> - may not define a equals or hashCode method.
> - must be a top-level class or a member of a statically accessible object
> - **can only have defs as members. In particular, it cannot have lazy vals, vars, or vals as members.**
> - cannot be extended by another class.

The bold ones excludes `Some` from being a Value Class as currently written. The second of these could probably be addressed by a slight change but the former kills it. You'd not be able to wrap another Value Class in `Some` if Some were made a Value Class itself.

Comment: that makes sense except value types work fine with generic parameters that can be a value class. The TestSome example in the OP that extends AnyVal totally compiles and works with a user defined value class.

Comment: Perhaps that restriction has been lifted. Additionally, `Some` inherits a bunch of collection traits and there may be violations of other Value Type constraints lurking there.

Comment: Some inherits only Option. Option inherits two traits -- Product and Serializable -- that both inherit Any.

Comment: I was confused by the inclusion of value members injected by the implicit option2Iterable. However, you missed a few supertypes. From the Scala Doc HTML for `Some[A]`: Linear Supertypes:
`Option[A]`, `Serializable`, `java.io.Serializable`, `Product`, `Equals`, `AnyRef`, `Any`.